# How to work with nested loops inside nested arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

So, I'm trying to work with nested loops to search through nested arrays, to find an specific value inside those, which is "codItem". This is the test model for the array (since I can't access the original fetch request on weekends):

```
let teste = [{
  item: [
    {
      codItem: 'Teste1'

    }
  ]
}, {
  item: [
    {
      codItem: 'Teste2'
    }
  ]
}, {
  item: [
    {
      codItem: 'Teste3'
    }
  ]
}];
```

This is the code I'm trying to use, based on some fundamental concepts and videos:

```
var items = teste.item;
for (i = 0; len = items.length; i < len, i++) {

  console.log(items);

  for (let properties in items[i]) {
    console.log(properties, items[i]);
  }




  var boxClonado = $("#boxMaster").clone(true);
  $(boxClonado).appendTo("#preparando").removeAttr("hidden", "style").addClass("clonados");

  $("#nomeproduto").append(teste[i].id);
  $("#quantidade").append(("Qntd.: " + teste.codItem));




}
```

... but at the moment, I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: items is undefined
at the first loop declaration line.

This is the last video I tried to reproduced and based the idea: https://youtu.be/AqgVLYpBWG8?t=604

Oh, the bottom part of the code refers to creating an infoBox for each item that shows up in "teste", and adding the info from "codItem" to "#nomeproduto" which is the name of the product.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since `teste` is an array `[]`, you can't use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#description) to access members of the array. Dot notation only works with objects `{}`.

Aside from that, you'd want to loop over `teste` with a nested loop over `teste[i]`.

Comment: code seems wrong, paste the original, this one contains too many syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`teste` is an array; it has no `item` property. You are trying to loop through `undefined`, thus you get the error.

Instead, loop through each item in the array, then, inside the loop, loop through each item in the current item's `item` property:

```js
let teste=[{item:[{codItem:"Teste1"}]},{item:[{codItem:"Teste2"}]},{item:[{codItem:"Teste3"}]}];

for(const items of teste){
  for(const item of items.item){
    let codItem = item.codItem;
    console.log(codItem)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Your solution works and helped me clear my path to be able to complete the task!

Comment: @lucas-ngr no problem :) glad to help